# Entity Framework Without Migration and Scaffolding (DB First Approach)

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I want to create **model class and dbcontext without migration and scaffolding**.
I am following **DB first approach**.
Please suggest any **Reference and Demo**.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at EF core  Power Tools

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, Yes gone through lots of example like Ef scaffolding, Fluent API. But i want only my project without Scaffolding & Fluent API. Don't wanna say I have resolved that by my own but it's takes too much time. MISSION ACCOMPLISHED !!!